# Why can't I edit one single typo in an answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have just tried to edit out a typo in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45447653/6066886

but the error message says I have to edit at least 6 characters...?

who thought this was a good idea? what's the reasoning behind this?
so I'll have to edit random stuff to get a typo out?

Comment: Please, read the answer in the linked question. It thoroughly explains the reasoning behind the minimum character count for suggested edits.

Comment: I've made an edit. Hopefully this is what you wanted.

Comment: There are ways... If it is important enough, you will discover them.

Comment: And if you cheat the rules often enough, moderators will discover *you*.